# How to avoid backslash from appear from ansible variable?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to run a task that ran perfectly on Ansible 1.9.4.

I know that some stuff has changed from Ansible 1.9.4 to 2.x.
My task is the following:

```
- name: find out if this version has a shared package
  stat: path="/home/"{{ users[0].name }}"/app/shared"
  become: yes
  become_user: "{{ users[0].name }}"
  register: sharedPackage
```

When I debugged, the output for stat is:

```
"/home/\"soma\"/soma/shared"
```

This `\"` it's causing me some trouble. How I remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove quotes from inside your path:

```
stat: path="/home/{{ users[0].name }}/app/shared"
```